# PHP - Using explode() function to assign values to an associative array

Tags: php

I'd like to explode a string, but have the resulting array have specific strings as keys rather than integers:

ie. if I had a string "Joe Bloggs", Id' like to explode it so that I had an associative array like:

```
$arr['first_name'] = "Joe";
$arr['last_name'] = "Bloggs";
```

at the moment, I can do:

```
$str = "Joe Bloggs";
$arr['first_name'] = explode(" ", $str)[0];
$arr['last_name'] = explode(" ", $str)[1];
```

which is inefficient, because I have to call explode twice.

Or I can do:

```
$str = "Joe Bloggs";
$arr = explode(" ", $str);
$arr['first_name'] = $arr[0];
$arr['last_name'] = $arr[1];
```

but I wonder if there is any more direct method.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would use [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine) like so:

```
$fields = array ( 'first_name', 'last_name' );
$arr = array_combine ( $fields, explode ( " ", $str ) );
```

EDIT: I would also pick this over using list() since it allows you to add fields should you require without making the list() call unnecessarily long.

Answer (score 10):

You can make use of [`list` <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) ([**Demo**](http://codepad.org/lF3WZyo6)):

```
$str = "Joe Bloggs";
list($arr['first_name'], $arr['last_name']) = explode(" ", $str);
```

`$arr` then is:

```
Array
(
    [last_name] => Bloggs
    [first_name] => Joe
)
```

Comment: Cheers for your answer and the demo.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot do `explode(" ", $str)[0]` in PHP <= 5.3.

However, you can do this:

```
list($arr['first_name'], $arr['last_name']) = explode(" ", $str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the warning re "explode(" ", $str)[0]"